# Postgres - Are multi-line statements atomic?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, postico

Here's an example:

```
create database users;
create table users (id int unique);
```

Then running these together:

```
insert into users values(1);
insert into users values(1);
```

I expected the first insert to succeed, but the second to fail. However what I am seeing is that they are run atomically, and no row is inserted. Here are the logs:

```
2021-11-08 23:04:37.825 UTC [181] LOG:  statement: insert into users values(1);
    insert into users values(1);

2021-11-08 23:04:37.825 UTC [181] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_id_key"
2021-11-08 23:04:37.825 UTC [181] DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
2021-11-08 23:04:37.825 UTC [181] STATEMENT:  insert into users values(1);
    insert into users values(1);
```

What's confusing is that there is no `BEGIN;` or `COMMIT;`. Are statements with multiple commands run atomically?

-- EDIT --

I am using Postico client to run these statements.

Comment: What client do you use to issue the statements? [Edit] the question and add the tag.

Comment: Postico - I edited the question.

Comment: Perhaps Postico has the autocommit mode disabled, so that both inserts run in the same transaction. Don't do that.

Comment: Wouldn't I expect to see BEGIN and COMMIT statements in the postgres logs though?